# I need help making a start/stop button in Javascript to control a slideshow. My full code is added below

Tags: javascript, html, css

My apologies for trying this question again but I am a beginner so I was too slow to figure out how to post my full code and my post got closed. I would like to add a button to control this slideshow in javascript. I took the suggestions offered from my prior post but I am still not getting it to work. The button has a class name of controls. Here I have posted my full code on jsfiddle. Hoping someone could help me get this start/stop button working. Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/tamtamToronto/eqk4rLus/9/#&togetherjs=R9ecgotDoP

````
        var slideIndex = 0;
        showSlides();

        function showSlides() {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            slideIndex++;
            if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
            clearInterval(slideInterval);
        }

        var playing = false;
        var playButton = document.getElementById('play');

        function playSlideshow() {
            playButton.innerHTML = '&#9658;'; // pause character
            playing = false;
            slideInterval = setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
        }

        function pauseSlideshow() {
            playButton.innerHTML = '&#10074;&#10074;'; // play character
            playing = true;
            clearInterval(slideInterval);
        }

        pauseButton.onclick = function () {
            if (playing) { pauseSlideshow(); }
            else { playSlideshow(); }
        };
</script>```
````

Comment: This is my first time using jsfiddle so please be patient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var playing = true;
var playButton = document.getElementById('play');

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  if(playing) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
  }
}

function toggleSlideshow() {
  if(playing) {
    playButton.innerHTML = '&#10074;&#10074;'; // pause character
    playing = false;
  } else {
    playButton.innerHTML = '&#9658;'; // play character
    playing = true;
    showSlides();
  }
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', toggleSlideshow);
```

```css
<style>
* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 1px;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body, h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.quote {
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  font-family: garamond, perpetua, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
}


.attribute {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding-top: 5px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: garamond, perpetua, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
}

.quoteboxlf {
  width: 55%;
  padding: 5%;
  top:0px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

.quoteboxrt {
  width: 55%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  top:0px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  margin: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .attribute {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

}
</style>
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="1.jpg" style=width:100% alt="1">
        <div class="quoteboxlf">
          <div class="quote">1 Dummy text here here.
          </div>
          <div class="attribute">Name goes here</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="2.jpg" style=width:100% alt="2">
        <div class="quoteboxrt">
          <div class="quote">2 Dummy text here here.
          </div>
          <div class="attribute">Name goes here</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="3.jpg" style=width:100% alt="3">
        <div class="quoteboxrt">
          <div class="quote">3 Dummy text here here.
          </div>
          <div class="attribute">Name goes here</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>

    <button class="controls" id="play">&#9658;</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. It may take me a while. I am slow.

Comment: Thank you dolmuchcu!! This is the answer I was looking for. I really appreciate you breaking it down for me. 

Comment: Happy to help @TamTaminToronto

Comment: Hey if you don't mind me asking how would I style that button in css. Is it
 .controls{}? or #play{}

Comment: You can do both, a class can be assigned to multiple elements but an id should be assigned only one element i mean id represent a unique element in a web page, whereas a class is more like a group that the element is a member of. [The difference between id and class](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 1):

you can control carousel with HTML code and use bootstrap class for design

```
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

Comment: This will talk with my current slideshow that runs by a function? Or would I need to redesign it?

Comment: You can use Bootstrap to redesign a carousel with HTML and CSS

Comment: It took me weeks to design the one I have. I am a total beginner. I have never used Bootstrap. Is there no way to get the code I have working?

Comment: you should use bootstrap for a carousel and its a better way to solve them, I try to write code in the below with bootstrap for you

Comment: I'll have a look thanks! It may take me a while to understand it.

Comment: No problem, I sent for you with this title `Use bootstrap for a carousel`

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap for a carousel

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```